# Native Script : DatePicker not working on iOS

Tags: react-native, nativescript, react-native-ios, nativescript-angular

I have used NativeScript datepicker and it is working fine with the Android application but I run the same application in iOS then it will occur crash the app.

code is given below which I used

```
 private openDropDownSelectionModal<T>(dropDownType: string, selectButtonText = 'Select Item', data?: T): Promise<any> {

    let modalDialogOptions: ModalDialogOptions = {
        context: {
            buttonText: selectButtonText,
            data: data
        },
        viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
    };
    let component: any = undefined;

    switch (dropDownType) {
        case 'date':
            component = DatePickerModalComponent;
            break;
        case 'time':
            component = TimePickerModalComponent;
            break;
        default:
            component = DropDownModalComponent
    }

    return this.modalDialogService.showModal(component, modalDialogOptions);
}
```

And call this function from here

```
public openDeadlineTimePickerSelectionModal() {
        this.openDropDownSelectionModal('time', 'Select Deadline Time', { date: this.deadlineDate })
            .then((selectedTime: Date) => {
                if (selectedTime) {
                    this.deadlineDate.setHours(selectedTime.getHours());
                    this.deadlineDate.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes());
                    this.deadlineDate.setSeconds(0);
                    const updatedTask = _.cloneDeep(this.task);
                    updatedTask.deadlineDate = this.deadlineDate;
                    this.saveTask(updatedTask);
                }
            });
    }
```

ERROR :

[image]

Comment: can you share the crash log from xcode?

Comment: @tejashwi : thanks for quick reply, please check my edit question

Comment: Are you using it inside some kind of scroll view? What's your iOS version? Are you using a simulator or an actual device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similar issues created on Native Script issue tracker, [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5937) and [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1460).

You can visit these links for more information, apart from that, if you are using `ScrollView` then try to wrap it inside `StackLayout`, something like below:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView #datePickerModalView>
            <StackLayout>
                <DatePicker #datePicker verticalAlignment="center" (loaded)="configure(datePicker)"></DatePicker>
                <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-active" [text]="buttonText" (tap)="selectDate(datePicker)"></Button>
                <Button class="btn" text="Cancel" (tap)="cancel()"></Button>                
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView> 
    </StackLayout>
`})
```

Comment: its not working, pls check my edit question, I have put there datepicker view also

Comment: @NayeemMansoori updated my answer, you need to wrap your ScrollView inside a StackLayout